# Data locality if HDFS not used

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

What happens to data locality feature of Map/Reduce portion of Hadoop when you provide it with a different storage other than HDFS like a MySql server and so on? In other words, my understanding is that Hadoop Map/Reduce uses data locality to try to launch a map task on the same node that the data is but when the data is stored in sql sever, there is no local data on the task node as all data are in the sql server node. So do we lose the data locality in that case or the definition of the data locality is changing? If it changes, what is the new defintion?

Comment: Which part of Hadoop?  MapReduce?

Comment: Not able to understand your question !!

Comment: I updated the question. Hopefully it is more clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no data locality if the data is not in the cluster. All the data must be copied from the remote source. This is the same as if the task cannot be run on a node that contains the data in HDFS. There are several input formats that use remote sources including S3, HBase and DB. If you can put your data in HDFS that is great. I use Mongo as a remote source quite regularly for small amounts of data that is frequently updated and I have been happy with the results.

Comment: Thanks for you response. Would you please give me some idea of what you mean small amounts of data? and also, how many concurrent mappers you launch for this small? I just want to get a overall picture.

Comment: My largest table is maybe 20MB in Mongo. I just use 1 mapper. How many mappers you use will be dependent on your sharding. Have a look at https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop.

Comment: I should add that size that this will work at is bound by network bandwidth.