# Data locality when using a different cluster's HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Similar to [Data locality if HDFS not used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171016/data-locality-if-hdfs-not-used), but specific to HDFS.

We have 2 hadoop clusters, and we're submitting a pig job to the cluster A JobTracker, that reads a big dataset (100GB) from cluster B and joins it to a small dataset (10 rows) from cluster A.

```
b_data = load 'hdfs://b-cluster/big.txt' as ( customer_id: chararray);
a_data = load 'hdfs://a-cluster/small.txt' as ( customer_id: chararray);
j_data = join a_data by acct_id left, b_data by customer_id;
dump j_data;
```

Surprisingly, it works + it takes almost the same time we're used to when working with only local datasets on cluster A (about 10 minutes)

What is happening technically?  Are the tasktrackers running only on A nodes? How are they reading the dataset from B datanodes? Why is it so fast, as they cannot possibly enjoy data locality, can they?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not submitting the pig job to cluster B and put the 10 rows into the distributed cache and join it from there? BTW we can't tell if your cluster A runs tasktrackers or not.

Comment: What do you mean by **that reads a big dataset (100GB) from cluster B**??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reality, the HDFS cluster and the MapReduce cluster have nothing to do with each other from a synchronization perspective... they are completely independent. It just happens to be that we often co-locate them to take advantage of data locality.

The job tracker will prefer assigning jobs in a data local way, but if it can't it'll just submit them to whatever task tracker*. At that point, reading from a local HDFS or a distant HDFS is the same mechanism: over the network. The protocols are the same so no problem!

As for why you aren't noticing slowdown, I'm not sure! Perhaps you have a fast network (10GigE?)! The task trackers are definitely getting data from the distant data nodes over the network. But, it is doing this in parallel. I think you'd notice at larger scale.

* I'm ignoring the rack locality step